# YouTube iFrame automatically opens YouTube app. How can I stop this?

Tags: html, youtube-api

I used the default YouTube iFrame for my website. My users have said that upon entering the web app, it redirects them to youtube. I find this annoying for me and for my users.

Is there any way I can stop this from happening?

Here is the code that is causing the YouTube app to open:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wCtedSNYBLc?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The site this is on can be found [here](http://inocydia.net/app).

Comment: what platform/browser are your users seeing this on? I just checked every desktop browser on a Mac and it seems to be working just fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "playsinline" parameter to play the video inline instead.